# How to use a regional endpoint in Google Speech-to-Text C# API?

Tags: c#, google-api, speech-to-text, google-speech-to-text-api

I would like to use the European endpoint **eu-speech.googleapis.com** for the Google Cloud speech recognition C# API. An example is given for Python at
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/endpoints#speech-sync-recognize-python

My credentials are stored in a json file.
When setting up the SpeechClient as follows, an *invalid authentication* exception is thrown:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Cloud.Speech.V1;
...
SpeechClientBuilder scb = new SpeechClientBuilder
{
    Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("mycredentials.json")
};
scb.Endpoint = "eu-speech.googleapis.com"; // Without this line everything works.
SpeechClient speechClient = scb.Build();
speechClient.Recognize(...);
```

Exception: *Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.*

How can I set the endpoint correctly?
Do I break my credentials when setting the endpoint?
Should the endpoint be included within the json file?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try https:// eu-speech.googleapis.com  (without the space ) while i google a bit more

Comment: With the https:// prefix the Recognize call is not returning, i.e. no exception is raised (good), but nothing else is happening.

Comment: Want to cross post this over on the [issue forum](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/tree/e04d0561688dec66080c8b7a96bb3ba021a035cb)

Comment: Ok, I will do so. I am using Google.Cloud.Speech.V1 version 3.0.0 by the way.

Comment: Issue has been created at https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/8798

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the C# API has an issue. Fortunately, Jon Skeet provided two workarounds:

```
var client = new SpeechClientBuilder
{
    GoogleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("mycredentials.json"),
    Endpoint = "eu-speech.googleapis.com"
}.Build();
```

Alternatively:

```
var client = new SpeechClientBuilder
{
    CredentialsPath = "mycredentials.json",
    Endpoint = "eu-speech.googleapis.com"
}.Build();
```

See issue at [Regional Endpoint cannot be set in SpeechClientBuilder in Google.Cloud.Speech.V1 version 3.0.0 #8798](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/8798)